# In Oracle, How can I see what tables people are using?

Tags: oracle

We are thnking of decommissioning some tables, but I need to determine if they are being used frequently or not.

In the end, I need a table name, # unique queries, # unique users.

How do I get that?  I can't find anything on the web that answers it.

Comment: You could query inside of `v$sql` for something like `%<table name>%` and that would tell you when the table is being accessed. Join that with `v$session` and you can see unique users.

Comment: Are the specific metrics you've mentioned critical?  Or are you just trying to figure out whether the objects are being used?  I'd generally prefer to look at things like segment-level I/O statistics (with appropriate caveats) but that won't tell you anything about the number of queries or users.  Getting queries and users will be painful and not 100% accurate because you'll need to regularly snapshot real-time views and process the results.

Comment: We are trying to figure out if something is being used, how often it is used, and who used it. Ultimate goal is to let them know we are dropping the table so that they have time to respond with "WAIT, don't do that yet!" (i.e. we don't impact the production environment).  Sounds like this may not be an easy thing to get from Oracle. Thanks for the time!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which features you're licensed for, you can:

- Read from `v$segment_statistics` and see which segments are in use. Easy mode, but it doesn't tell you who is using the table.
- Set up statspack to sample at a relatively fine granularity and examine the tables being used in there. Medium difficulty and medium accuracy, your data won't be 100% accurate, but at least you'll have a better idea.
- Sample `v$session_wait` and correlate the `p1` and `p2` columns with file# and block# - this tells you which table/index is involved. Hard mode, but now you know roughly who is doing the reads and how often.
- Read from `v$active_session_history` if you're licensed for AWR. Hard & expensive mode, but now you REALLY know who is doing the reads and with incredible accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

To echo commments from above, I'd use a statistics report but, it requires the STATSPACK tool.

The following procedures can be used to monitor the performance of an Oracle database between two points in time (a “snapshot”), which then produces a reports that can be used for the analysis described above.

- In SQL*Plus, log in with the “system” id
- enter the following command to take the first “snap”:

  ```
  EXECUTE DBMS_WORKLOAD_REPOSITORY.CREATE_SNAPSHOT();
  ```
- make note of the resulting “snap id”
- use the same command above to take the second “snap” to include all activity to be monitored
- also make note of this “snap id”
- use the following command to generate the “AWR report”:

  ```
  @$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/awrrpt.sql
  ```
- when prompted, enter the “snap id” of the first and second “snaps”
- a resulting report will be generated with the specified name

*TIP: If there is a particular time of day when the system experiences peak activity, it is best to take a “snap” before and after this timeframe to maximize the amount of statistics to be captured in the resulting report.*

Comment: But AWR only lists the top N queries by different metrics.  It's possible a table will be used hundreds of times and not show up in the report.